# How do I enable Devise to send out confirmation emails on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, actionmailer

I am on heroku so am not clear where and how to set it up so that devise can send out emails.

I actually have two directions to go:

1. I am using sendgrid, so am wondering how it works with that.
2. For my hand-rolled mailers, I use PostageApp, which I'd prefer because it allows me to see what's going on with my email.  The way I use PostageApp is my Mailers are a class of PostageApp's mailer.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also using PostageApp which has its own mailer as a sub-class of 
ActionMailer. I wonder how can I have Devise's Mailer use PostageApp. Is it possible to override the whole devise_mailer.rb, or only the methods that are required? or should I edit the devise_mailer.rb directly? I'm a little confused. Any help appreciated. Check this thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/plataformatec-devise/nraDpM5PDd4/discussion

Comment: yes I am having the same questions...from what I have read, it is supposedly only the methods that are required...but I don't understand why that would be the case.

Comment: Let me know if you find out, I'll keep trying too,thanks!

Comment: Hey Angela, Benjamin actually got it to work (I think!) on PostageApp, check out this thread: http://help.postageapp.com/discussions/support/176-how-can-i-make-the-devisemailer-a-subclass-of-postageapp

Comment: If his mailer is a sublcass of the DeviseMailer....how do we inherit the PostageApp class?

Comment: Hey Angela, just wanted to let you guys know that with the help of one of our customers, we have been able to add integration instructions for Devise with Postage on our documentation. You can find it here: http://help.postageapp.com/kb/quick-start-guides/ruby (At the bottom of the page) He has also told us that he is updating the code to work with the newer, modularized version of Devise, and he will give us the code as soon as it is ready. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to let you guys know that with the help of one of our customers, we have been able to add [integration instructions for Devise with Postage](http://help.postageapp.com/kb/quick-start-guides/ruby) to our documentation. He has also told us that he is updating the code to work with the newer, modularized version of Devise, and he will give us the code as soon as it is ready.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 3 I used the following settings in config/environments/production.rb

```
# Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '##YOUR_PROJECTNAME##.heroku.com' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address    => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port       => 25,
  :user_name  => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password   => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain     => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
  :authentication  => :plain
}
```

Note: you'll need to substitute in your project name - but all those ENV variables are populated for you automatically by heroku.